# How can I retrieve my questions on deleted proposals in Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

I see that some questions I proposed in Area 51 disappeared from the [*Example Questions* list in my user profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/51707/franck-dernoncourt?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_posts). I assume this is because some proposal got deleted. Is there any way to retrieve my questions on deleted proposals in Area 51?

Comment: If the whole proposal is deleted, I fear there's nothing you can do. If only specific questions are deleted, you should still be able to see them given direct link, but like in all Stack Exchange sites, they are not listed in the profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, if so I guess I should turn my question into a feature request as I'm not a huge fan of the user content being removed.

Comment: Do you have link to the deleted proposal? There's good chance it's hard deleted for good, without a data dump, but also a chance it does have a data dump.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well no, I proposed questions for tens of proposals, I don't know which ones disappeared :-/ Ideally I'd like to have a list of the questions I asked on deleted proposals, without having to dig into each deleted proposal.

Comment: Try contacting a Community Manager in chat then and ask him/her to give you a hand. Tim Post is roaming the Tavern sometimes and can be pinged there, and Anna Lear might also be able to help if she's around. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks but I am looking for a solution that would be available to anyone at anytime. Since the feature is not present, shall I create a new question and phrase it as a feature request? Or shall I instead edit this question?

Comment: You can edit this into a feature request, but keep in mind most requests takes long time to get official attention.